# Handling bad records in csv file using pyspark permissive mode

Tags: pyspark

How do I display only the corrupted records in a csv file using permissive mode in Pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the column "_corrupt_record" to the schema and impose the schema, the input for corrupted records are put in the column, and if it's not corrupted, the _corrupt_record column is gonna be null.
Check out the following link from databricks documentation:  https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/read-csv-corrupt-record.html